# Null geometry values on GeoJSON file in Tableau

Tags: geojson, geopandas, tableau

I am using GeoPandas to combine several Shapefiles into one but I am running into an issue.

If I export to a .shp file, my column names get ruined because of the 10 character limit. However, the geometry field in Tableau works as intended.

When I export the exact same thing out as a GeoJSON, the text itself looks right but Tableau doesn't seem to recognize the values in the geometry column. All I have are null values. Any ideas on what I should be looking out for?